# best way to control the width of a leaflet label

Tags: r, leaflet

What is the best way to wrap long leaflet tooltip labels? This question is *not* about leaflet popups.

For example:

```
library(leaflet)

# an exceedingly long text label
gettysburg.address <- "Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent, a new nation, conceived in Liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal. Now we are engaged in a great civil war, testing whether that nation, or any nation so conceived and so dedicated, can long endure. We are met on a great battle-field of that war. We have come to dedicate a portion of that field, as a final resting place for those who here gave their lives that that nation might live. It is altogether fitting and proper that we should do this."

leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(lng=-77.229797, lat=39.819410,
             # an exceedingly long text label
             label = htmltools::HTML(gettysburg.address))
```

One option, of course, is to manually insert an HTML line break at the desired intervals. This works fine, but it isn't practical when generating lots of labels.

```
wrapped.gettysburg.address <- paste("Four score and seven years ago our fathers", "<br>", 
                            "brought forth on this continent, a new nation,", "<br>", 
                            "conceived in Liberty, and dedicated to the proposition", "<br>", 
                            "that all men are created equal. Now we are engaged in a", "<br>", 
                            "great civil war, testing whether that nation, or any", "<br>", 
                            "nation so conceived and so dedicated, can long endure.", "<br>", 
                            "We are met on a great battle-field of that war. We have", "<br>", 
                            "come to dedicate a portion of that field, as a final", "<br>", 
                            "resting place for those who here gave their lives that", "<br>", 
                            "that nation might live. It is altogether fitting and", "<br>", 
                            "proper that we should do this.")

leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(lng=-77.229797, lat=39.819410,
             # an exceedingly long text label
             label = htmltools::HTML(wrapped.gettysburg.address))
```

I can imagine a couple different solutions.

1. set some leaflet specific style argument that controls the width of the tooltip label box. **I haven't been able to find this argument, if it exists.**
2. Use a function to insert `<br>` at regular intervals in the label text, and then wrap the label with `htmltools::HTML`, as in the example above.

Is there a pre-existing function like `stringr::str_wrap` than inserts HTML breaks instead? Alternatively, is there a way to directly control the width of the leaflet label box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# an exceedingly long text label
gettysburg.address <- "Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent, a new nation, conceived in Liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal. Now we are engaged in a great civil war, testing whether that nation, or any nation so conceived and so dedicated, can long endure. We are met on a great battle-field of that war. We have come to dedicate a portion of that field, as a final resting place for those who here gave their lives that that nation might live. It is altogether fitting and proper that we should do this."

leaf <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(lng=-77.229797, lat=39.819410,
             # an exceedingly long text label
             label = htmltools::HTML(gettysburg.address))
```

**use custom css code**

```
library(htmltools)
browsable(
  tagList(list(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(
        ".leaflet-tooltip{ width: 150px; white-space: normal; }"
      )
    ),
    leaf
  ))
)
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice, thank you. Do you have any idea if an HTML version of `stringr::str_wrap` exists? Although it isn't necessary for this situation, I could imagine it being useful in other circumstances.